# Two threads have references to unshared instances of unsynchronized class. Threading issues?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I haven't done any threading in years, need a bit of a reset:

If I have multiple instances of a class will two threads need synchronization even if they talk to different instances?

Example

Let's say I have a class with a method. The method increments a counter and returns the current count.

There are two threads. Each thread has its own instance of the counter class and calls the method repeatedly. There is no locking or synchronization. Will the threads step on each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There are two threads. Each thread has its own instance of the counter class and calls the method repeatedly. There is no locking or synchronization. Will the threads step on each other?

no they won't as long as the data written to in one thread is not read from another thread.

That specific multithreading strategy is called Thread confinement: you don't share anything across threads. That is one of the simplest way to make your program thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for any locking or synchronization unless both of the threads update the same instance of the counter. If they both have a counter instance, and they only read/write their own counter instance, there will be no problems.

Comment: @MedicineMan I'm not the downvoter, but I'm thinking its because `"unless the threads share something"` could be more specific. That first sentence isn't very helpful, someone may have only read that part.

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any `static` fields (which are inherently shared between class instances) nor concurrent external data access (files, streams, DDE, databases etc) you shouldn't encounter any threading issues.

Since both `static` fields and all concurrent external data objects are "unique", you'd have to synchronize on access with them. That's exactly why it's advised to use immutables & don't use `static` data in multi-threaded runs, *unless* you're having the data mutable/static for some synchronization-related reasons (e.g. as locks etc).

Note that a counter is essentially mutable by definition (it changes its state) - but in most real-life cases you can safely use immutable objects (Strings, immutable collections etc)

Further reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/immutable.html

Answer (score 0):

If only 1 Thread is accessing a given Object / field in an object, it will be thread-safe.

Example:

```
public class ThreadSafe {
  int counter;
  public void increment() {...}
}

public class NotThreadSafe {
  static int counter;
  public static void increment() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is bit complicated  but seeing your rating on stack-exchange i assume you would be able to digest it:

Well as we both know that a object comprises of data and methods.
when ever we create an object the "data part/instance variable/fields (they are all same name for data that is global in a class) " of the object is stored in a data structure in the memory that we call heap space. This data structure can be referenced by "this pointer".
So it means that if we have two different object they will have different this pointer.
Methods do not have any independent allocation.
When ever we execute a method like
obj1.feature()
it means apply the "feature" on obj1. During this process the run time system will pass "this pointer" of obj1 to "feature".
Internal variable in a method are allocated space on a data structure called as frame that is pushed on the stack. any variable that is not declared inside the method is assumed to be in the global data structure and the pointer to it is appended automatically thus, globalvaraiabe becomes this.globalvariable
So we can see clearly that if we pass different "this pointer" to the method they will access completely different memory locations and hence do not require thread synchronization.